# MySQL: what is AUTO_INCREMENT “free space”?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

Quote from [openark-kit](http://code.openark.org/forge/openark-kit). The software seems unmaintained (Google Code hosted and last commit from 2013).

> oak-show-limits: show `AUTO_INCREMENT` “free space”.

What is this? How-to see `AUTO_INCREMENT` “free space” without this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the max id the auto_increment can reach.

You can make the same with the following SQL :

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    `AUTO_INCREMENT` current_id, 
    if(m.max_id =-1,'18446744073709551615',m.max_id) max_id, 
    (m.max_id - `AUTO_INCREMENT`) free_id,
    (`AUTO_INCREMENT`/m.max_id*100) percent_used
FROM  
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME,
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        CASE 
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "tinyint%unsigned"    THEN 255
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "tinyint%"    THEN 127
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "smallint%unsigned"   THEN 65535
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "smallint%"   THEN 32767
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "mediumint%unsigned"  THEN 16777215
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "mediumint%"  THEN 8388607
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "int%unsigned"    THEN 4294967295
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "int%"    THEN 2147483647
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "bigint%unsigned" THEN 18446744073709551615
            WHEN COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "bigint%" THEN 9223372036854775807
        END max_id
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE extra like "%auto_increment%" 
    ) m
    on 
        t.TABLE_NAME = m.TABLE_NAME
        AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = m.TABLE_SCHEMA
-- WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
-- AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

## [oak-show-limits](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Vgh3EJQn6vMJ:shlomi-noach.github.io/openarkkit/oak-show-limits.html+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr&client=ubuntu)

> NAME
>
> oak-show-limits: show AUTO_INCREMENT "free space"
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> Show all AUTO_INCREMENT columns, current AUTO_INCREMENT values and
>   upper bounds, usage ratio, on all schemata and on all tables:
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> oak-show-limits looks for AUTO_INCREMENT columns, and compares current
>   values with the column type. It reports those columns where the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value is higher than a given threshold. This utility
>   can be used for diagnosing underestimated and overestimated data type
>   ranges. Underestimated data types are those in which the
>   AUTO_INCRMENET current value is approaching the upper limit.
>   Overestimated data types are those where the current value is
>   extremely far from the upper limit. Output is in tab delimited, where
>   each row specifies: